# Ошибка argument label '(String:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idTable") as! TableViewCell
    let URL = NSURL(String: arrayOfURL[indexPath.row])
    //let URL = NSURL(string: "https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-28639294&id=456244781&hash=704a23ae4dfd10f0&__ref=vk.api&api_hash=1479374300a44cd0ffe4586e5649_GI3DKNBWGE3DA")
    cell.videoView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)
    cell.titleLabel.text = "asdas"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

исправь строку

```
   let URL = NSURL(String: arrayOfURL[indexPath.row])
```

на:

```
  let URL = NSURL(string: arrayOfURL[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: а в чем разница?

Comment: в написании названия аргумента - string пишется с маленькой буквы. Swift чуствителен к регистру

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забудь отметить ответ, как правильный

Comment: я еще не проверил

Answer (score 0):

Лучше предлагаю тебе сделать так:

```
...
guard let urlStr = arrayOfURL[indePath.row] as? String, 
      let URL = NSURL(string: urlStr)
else {return fatalError()}
...
```

Так ты обезопасишь себя во первых от optional, во вторых от того, что в массиве не вернется String. Ну и можно немного переставить местами код в методе, чтобы было еще лучше если подразумевается, что у тебя точно будут урлы для видео(а их отсутствие - не допустимо)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idTable") as! TableViewCell
cell.titleLabel.text = "asdas"
guard let urlStr = arrayOfURL[indePath.row] as? String, 
      let URL = NSURL(string: urlStr)
else {return fatalError()}

cell.videoView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)

return cell
```

}

Ну или так, если урлов может не быть

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idTable") as! TableViewCell
   cell.titleLabel.text = "asdas"
    if let urlStr = arrayOfURL[indePath.row] as? String{
      let URL = NSURL(string: urlStr)
      cell.videoView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)
   } 
return cell
```